# Python plot and heavy computation

Tags: python, matplotlib

Python matplotlib interactive plots become unresponsive if there is heavy computation after the plot. Is there a way to create an additional thread for qt window so that the job will not block during interaction with the plot?

E.g.

```
plt.scatter(x,y)
difficult_job()
```

Thanks

Comment: I think if you do add `plt.show()` before the difficult_job call, the plot would be shown before the next line is executed.

Comment: It shows but it becomes unresponsive

Comment: I don't know of any way to avoid that but another possible way might be to save the plot as an image file.

Comment: I assume you're using IPython, as otherwise `plt.show()` would block execution until the plot window is closed. A very simplistic solution could be to add `plt.waitforbuttonpress(timeout=-1)` after `plt.show()`, which should block execution until you press a key or click your mouse in the plot. Note that this may not work with all backends (it works with qt) and that it may trigger a deprecation warning (which can be ignored). As for more sophisticated solutions, threading won't work (matplotlib is not thread safe) but you could maybe do something with multiprocessing.